# Bq not working after upgrading to OTA 12. Ubuntu touch, phone

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-touch, phone, bq

Bq 4.5 not working after OTA 12
After upgrading to the last OTA 12 version, bq 4.5 stepped wworking.
I downloaded the upgrade and authorized the system reboot. After 1:30h, it was still stuck at the 'Ubuntu...... ....' screen. Then, I turned the screen off. After 10 min I turned it on and I got the same screen. I have it plugged in, but this screen is the only thing I get. My phone is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried:

Go into fastboot-mode (hold VolumeUp + Power)
Connect via USB to PC
in Ubuntu: type in Terminal:
ubuntu-device-flash touch --bootstrap --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --recovery-image recovery.img

as suggested here: https://m.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/2zljaw/ubuntu_phone_aquaris_e45_ubuntu_edition/

I got this answer:
2016/07/27 18:08:24 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2016/07/27 18:08:24 Device is |krillin|
2016/07/27 18:08:25 Flashing version 34 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device krillin
can't flash recovery image

Comment: Solved!

I download the recovery image from http://people.canonical.com/~jhm/barajas/recovery-krillin.img
and repeated the commands. It worked! Thanks to Pat McGowan, from Canonical.

Comment: I have the E5 and have performed the update all OK. just trying to find out what is new in it, as the first thing I noticed was the Location icon.

Comment: If thia question has now been resolved ppease indicate it by highlighting the tick by the answer.

Comment: Yes, my OTA12 update went OK and I get the location icon,  but location still does not work since OTA11

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem.
I let the phone trying to boot al night but it didn't work.
I reported this right now as a bug in launchpad, so consider to subscribe the bug if you are affected.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-image/+bug/1607251

Regards.